# Authenticate Spring Restful using Spring Security at Swing

Tags: java, spring, swing, rest

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/2011/10/31/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security-3-1-part-3/)
now, just authenticated person who can see the response. 
If not authorized people, will got 401 response.
I try use postman chrome to simulate it, the scenarion is work.
Then I try to consume the rest server via swing, 
is this able to do? post username and password to j_security_check to get token?
I try to using querystring get, and post it but failed.

```
// test sending GET request
String requestURL =  txtHost.getText()+"j_spring_security_check";
try {
    HttpUtility.sendGetRequest(requestURL+String.format( "?j_username=%s&j_password=%s",txtUserName.getText(), txtPassword.getText()));
    String[] response = HttpUtility.readMultipleLinesRespone();
    for (String line : response) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

HttpUtility.disconnect();
```

Post failed too:

```
// test sending POST request
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
String requestURL = txtHost.getText() + "j_spring_security_check";
params.put("j_username",txtUserName.getText());
params.put("j_password", txtPassword.getText());

try {
    HttpUtility.sendPostRequest(requestURL, params);
    String[] response = HttpUtility.readMultipleLinesRespone();
    for (String line : response) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

HttpUtility.disconnect();
```

That is at Login button
[image]

Comment: Try to POST rather than get. And the username/password must be in the body not in URL. Also your Spring might require CSRF token value. Press F12 in your browser and check what is actually sent.

Comment: Is that able to do? when I post something from swing and try to investigate response at browser using f12? What plugin need to install at browser? Is there any video at youtube?

Comment: Post from browser, see what's sent, do the same in swing

Comment: Oh, yes of course. I have tried using postman, but I want to try make client using swing. Just for simulation.